# Running all python codes saved in a folder from Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python

Is there any python code I can use to automatically detect all ipynb files saved inside a specific folder and run them sequentially?

I can identify them all using this function:

```py
path = glob.iglob(f"/Users/[...]")
```

But unfortunately I cannot run them using

for file in path
%run file

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: "But unfortunately I cannot run them using" - well, yes; that's because `%run file` is **not Python code**, but a special command to Jupyter. These cannot be mixed and matched with Python.

Comment: Your title and your first line are a complete mismatch and that is why you are getting poor answers. Title: "Running all python codes saved in a folder from Jupyter Notebook". <-- That title would mean to run all python code (ending in `.py` as Elkhan addresses. Also from the title, I'd take the 'from Jupyter Notebook' at the end to mean you want to run the code to do the task inside a Jupyter notebook. **By contrast**, you just ask for Python code in the first sentence, but then as Karl points out, your example is using IPython magic (Juputer inherits that). And then in your first sentence...

Comment: <continued> you say "to automatically detect all ipynb files saved inside a specific folder ". So you want to be detecting `.ipynb` files and not `.py` files. Your comments in replies and additional things help clear up some of this, but you want to endeavor to not make those trying to help you struggle to determine what you are really asking. The big question you don't seem to address yet is whether you do wish to run this process to execute all your notebooks in a Jupyter notebook or as a Python script? Either way the easiest would be to use [jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) ...

Comment: <continued> to execute each notebook. It is easier than using `jupyter nbconvert` directly, which you could also use for executing the notebooks in place. So you iterate on your glob running each notebook with `'jupytext` or `jupyter nbconevert`. See [here](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html#command-line-conversion) for the jupytext command specifics. See [here](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html) for the command for `jupyter nbconvert`. You can use `os.system('<command>')` whether using a Python script or Jupyter to run the commands. If you ...

Comment: <continued> specify wheter you are going to do this iterating on your glob object from within a Jupyter notebook or within a script, I can provide more specifics. Jupyter has some conveniences that you can take advantage. But pure Python versions would work, too. Something along the lines of what Elkhan is getting at, but I would suggest `os.system()` instead of `subprocess` as it is easier to programmatically write out the long commands needed for `jupytext` or `jupyter nbconvert` commands and combining them into something to run using `os.system()` and f-strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import subprocess

# Get a list of files in the directory
files = os.listdir('Yourdirectory')

py_files = [f for f in files if f.endswith('.py')]

py_files.sort()

for file in py_files:
    subprocess.run(['python', file])
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

Unfortunately this does not work as my file ends with ipynb.

If I print (files), the response is [].

I tried replacing .py with .ipynb.

Now the file is found (when I print it, I can see it) but the code you shared still cannot run the file:

The error message I receive says:

Error msg: python: can't open file + No such file or directory

Comment: Did you use from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor?

Comment: Executing them with that?

Comment: I am really sorry but I am not understanding this solution. Is there any chance you could share the code so I can test it directly?

Comment: I generally do not use jupyter notebook so I do not have a file like that. I can not reproduce question but I'm working on it.

Comment: For anyone using this to run all the Python script files in a directory, if the scripts themselves are going to spawn new scripts then you need to check for more `.py` files added. The code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75087369/8508004) will do that. It is written to run inside a Jupyter Notebook. So you'd have to adapt the `%run` step to  do something like Ellkhan uses with subprocess or use `os.system()`. Also it is set up to run files in the same directory as the notebook. You'd have to adapt it for a sub-directory if you are looking for something like OP is for a specific folder.